# Splitting field of $x^5 - t$ over $\mathbb{F}_{11}(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I'm trying to solve a question which asks me to find the degree of the splitting field of $x^5 - t$ over $\mathbb{F}_{11}(t)$.

I honestly have no idea where to begin - the only other examples of splitting fields I've done have been over $\mathbb{Q}$ which was very easy to work with.

I saw [Degree of a splitting field over $ \mathbb{F}_{4}(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200986/degree-of-a-splitting-field-over-mathbbf-4t) which looks somewhat similar, but the answers there involve Galois groups which I don't think I'm supposed to use because I haven't encountered them in the course yet.

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: What are the possible degrees of the splitting field? Eliminate the impossible ones and you'll quickly arrive at the answer. Also, you haven't encountered Galois groups when learning about splitting fields? That's pretty curious.

Comment: @DonThousand we're moving onto Galois groups soon, just haven't got that far yet. I know the degree of the splitting field is bounded by $n!$ where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial, but that still leaves a lot to choose from - what am I missing?

Comment: Well, note that one root of the polynomial is $t^{\frac15}$, and all of the other roots can be generated from this root. So, the field is equivalent to $$\mathbb F_{11}\big(t\big)\bigg(t^{\frac15}\bigg)$$ So, the degree of the extension is either $1$ or $5$.

Comment: Ah of course, it seems so obvious now. Thanks for your help!